# Why $scope.variable in ChildController is not resolving to the $scope.variable in ParentController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Why in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/Lqp79/1/) `$scope.counter` inside `ChildController3` do not resolve to `ParenctController`'s `$scope.counter` but creates a `counter` on local `$scope`?

Replicating Code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app'>
   <div ng-controller="ParentController">    
       <h2>ChildController1</h2>
        <div ng-controller="ChildController1">
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
            <button ng-click="subtract()">Subtract</button>
        </div>
       <h2>ChildController2</h2>
       <div ng-controller="ChildController2">
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
            <button ng-click="subtract()">Subtract</button>
           <br/>
            {{ counter }} <- this is in local scope
        </div>
        {{ counter }} <- this is in parent scope
       <h2>ChildController3</h2>
        <div ng-controller="ChildController3">            
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
            <button ng-click="subtract()">Subtract</button>
            <br/>
            {{ counter }} <- this is in local scope
        </div> 

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('ParentController', function($scope) 
            {
               $scope.counter = 5;
            });

app.controller('ChildController1', function ($scope) {

            $scope.add = function () { 
                 $scope.counter += 1; 
            };
            $scope.subtract = function () { 
                $scope.counter -= 1;
            };
        });

app.controller('ChildController2',function($scope) {

            $scope.add = function () { 
                $scope.$parent.counter += 1; 
            };
            $scope.subtract = function () { 
                $scope.$parent.counter -= 1;
            };
        });

app.controller('ChildController3', function($scope) {

            $scope.add = function () { 
                $scope.counter += 1; 
            };
            $scope.subtract = function () { 
                $scope.counter -= 1;
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the scopes of different levels in the hierarchy share scope using prototypical inheritance.

A pure JS example would be:

```
function A(){
    this.count = 5;
}

function B(){       
}

a = new A();
B.prototype = a;
b = new B();

console.log(a.count,b.count); // gives 5 5    <--- shared

a.count++;

console.log(a.count,b.count);  // give 6 6    <----- still shared

b.count++;

console.log(a.count,b.count); // gives 6 7   <----- link broken

a.count++;
```

The link is broken because after "b.count++;" b really has a count property, before that it was just a prototype property.

More info on this can be found here: [Angular scope docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: Yess I know scopes are shared using prototypal inheritance. But then why `ChildController3.$scope.counter` inside `ChildController3.add()` doesnt resolves to `ParentController.$scope.counter`?, I mean without using `$scope.$parent`

Comment: It does resolve to it, until you change it. `Setting $scope.counter+=1`, is like saying `$scope.counter = $scope.$parent.counter+1` the first time its run

Comment: so while accessing a member variable of `$scope`, it resolves to `$scope.$parent`, but while writing to a member variable of `$scope`, it creates a new one, is this the same behavior as plain JS prototypal inheritance?

Comment: Yep, that's my understanding. Which was why I demoed that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
   <div ng-controller="ParentController">    
       <h2>ChildController1</h2>
        <div ng-controller="ChildController1">
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
            <button ng-click="subtract()">Subtract</button>
        </div>
       <h2>ChildController2</h2>
       <div ng-controller="ChildController2">
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
            <button ng-click="subtract()">Subtract</button>
           <br/>
            {{ number.counter }} <- this is in local scope
        </div>
        {{ number.counter }} <- this is in parent scope
       <h2>ChildController3</h2>
        <div ng-controller="ChildController3">            
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
            <button ng-click="subtract()">Subtract</button>
            <br/>
            {{ number.counter }} <- this is in local scope
        </div> 

    </div>
</div>


var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('ParentController', function($scope) 
            {
                $scope.number = {};
                $scope.number.counter = 5;
            });

app.controller('ChildController1', function ($scope) {

            $scope.add = function () { 
                 $scope.number.counter += 1; 
            };
            $scope.subtract = function () { 
                $scope.number.counter -= 1;
            };
        });

app.controller('ChildController2',function($scope) {

            $scope.add = function () { 
                $scope.$parent.number.counter += 1; 
            };
            $scope.subtract = function () { 
                $scope.$parent.number.counter -= 1;
            };
        });

app.controller('ChildController3', function($scope) {

            $scope.add = function () { 
                $scope.number.counter += 1; 
            };
            $scope.subtract = function () { 
                $scope.number.counter -= 1;
            };
        });
```

This happens because you´re overwriting your $scope.counter inside 'ChildController3'.

here, see this video at 30 min to see a better explanation about this:
[AngularJS MTV Meetup: Best Practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY)

What happened here to make it work was because you declared "$scope.number = {};" inside "ParentController", so when you use it "$scope.number.counter" inside "ChildController3" you made a reference to ParentController instead of before when you just overwrote "$scope.counter" inside of "ChildController3".